# where is svn file history stored?

Tags: svn

Where are the checkin comments for a SVN commit stored? Are they associated as a property with a specific revision of the file/directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are stored in the `svn:log` property. You can add the `--revprop` flag to the various property commands to view & edit this property.

```
$ svn log FILE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1234 | jkugelman | 2011-01-01 12:34:56 -0500 (Sat, 1 Jan 2011) | 1 line

Log message.

$ svn proplist --revprop -r 1234 FILE
Unversioned properties on revision 1234:
  svn:log
  svn:author
  svn:date

$ svn propget  --revprop -r 1234 svn:log FILE
Log message.

$ svn propedit --revprop -r 1234 svn:log FILE
<opens vim>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @detunized mentioned, they're stored in the svn database on the server.  Each commit creates one revision which has associated revision properties like `svn:author` and `svn:log` which has the log message.  Unlike file changes in a revision, revision properties can be changed after the fact.